# Bootstrap Tooltip Issues (Not Working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I've been having issues for a while with Bootstrap Tooltip and every solution found on the web was to no avail. The Bootstrap does not display any I don't understand as to why. It may be caused by including JQuery to help initialize but that solution also did not work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my entire code, only used to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Tooltip Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row" >
                    <h2>Tooltip Test</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="username">Username&nbsp;</label>
                    <input id="username" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test"> <!--TOOLTIP TO BE DISPLAYED-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!--TOOLTIP INITIALIZE-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have jQuery with the rest of your dependencies.

Comment: add jQuery before of bootstrap js file

Comment: Thanks guys, seems to be working quite well now, it was including the JQuery before the bootstrap